# Grid display separates when viewed fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble understanding whats going on with a grid I created. I made some code for a grid via javascript that changes the cell color when the mousepointer passes over it, however whenever I view this grid in a fullscreen window the view of the grid changes to four separate columns. This only happens when I look at the grid in fullscreen however, when viewing the grid in any smaller sized window it looks exactly how you envison a grid; with no spaces in between columns.

gridProblem

[image: 1]
This is how the grid looks fullscreen with the spacing issue shown

grid solution

[image: 2]
This is how the grid looks in any window sizing outside of maximized, and how I would like the grid to display 100% of the time.

Just in case, here is the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Etch N Sketch</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="container"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const board = document.getElementById("container");
for (x=0; x <= 15; x++) {
    const cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.className = "cells";
    cell.setAttribute("style", "height: 200px; width: 200px; color: black;");
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    cell.style.border = "solid 2px";
    cell.style.borderColor = "black";
    board.style.columnGap = "0px";
    board.style.display ="grid";
    board.style.gridTemplateColumns = "auto auto auto auto";
    board.appendChild(cell);
    cell.addEventListener("mouseover", change = () => 
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "red")
    cell.addEventListener("mouseout", reset = () => cell.style.backgroundColor = "blue")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you set the width and height to be absolute values here

`cell.setAttribute("style", "height: 200px; width: 200px; color: black;");`

so at a smaller screen size 200px is fine but once the area that the squares need to cover becomes larger than 200px your limiting them by having these values tied to them.

Comment: So would setting the width and height to auto solve the issue in your opinion? Or perhaps a percentage?

Comment: Setting them to auto probably wont work because it doesnt look like the parent container has a height / width declared. I would experiment with something like, `cell.setAttribute("style", "min-height: 200px; min-width: 200px; color: black;");` which is basically allowing the cells to grow larger than 200px but also setting a baseline for them.

Comment: Did this with the background div and got some good results! I wish I could upvote you, thanks!

Comment: @seemwavy no problem dawg, just happy to help!